# Complex Meta Query not returning wanted results

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $ajs_cat,
        )
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'price_min',
                'value'     => array($min_price, $max_price),
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'price_max',
                'value'     => array($min_price, $max_price),
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
            ),
        )
    );
```

I am trying to return acts based on a searched budget minimum (price_min) and maximum (price_max).

So if act 'X' has a minimum fee of 3000 (price_min) and a maximum fee of 6000 (price_max)

Search A: ('X' is in results)

I search with a budget of minimum of 3000 ($min_price) and a maximum of 5500 ($max_price) i get 'X' returned in the results.

Search B: ('X' is not in results)

I search with a budget of minimum of 3500 ($min_price) and a maximum of 5500 ($max_price) i would expect to see 'X' returned in the results as i could still afford him given my budget.

I need 'X' to return in both instances

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: tru to use relation "and" instead of or

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be

```
array(
                'key'       => 'price_min',
                'value'     => $min_price,
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'price_max',
                'value'     => $max_price,
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
```

Comment: When searching for price_min=3500&price_max=5500 it's returning results outside of the ranges. i.e, acts with of 6000 (price_min) - 10000(price_max)

Answer (score 1):

### If you selected both minimum and maximum price than your query like ::

```
array(
    'key'     => 'meta_key_min_price',
    'value'   => array( $min_p, $max_p ),
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
array(
    'key'     => 'meta_key_max_price',
    'value'   => array( $min_p, $max_p ),
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
),
```

---

### If you select only one of them than your query look like this ::

For Minimum

```
array(
    'key'     => 'meta_key_min_price',
    'value'   =>  $min_p,
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'compare' => '>=',
),
```

For Maximum

```
 array(
    'key'     => 'meta_key_max_price',
    'value'   =>  $min_p,
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'compare' => '<=',
),
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
$tax_query = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $ajs_cat,
    )
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'price_min',
            'value'     =>  $min_price,
            'compare'   => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'price_max',
            'value'     => $max_price,
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
    )
);
```